# HttpListener Server Header c#

Tags: c#, http, httplistener

I am trying to write a C# http server for a personal project, i am wondering how i can change the returned server header from Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0, to something else?

```
 public class HttpWebServer
    {
        private HttpListener Listener;

        public void Start()
        {
            Listener = new HttpListener();
            Listener.Prefixes.Add("http://*:5555/");
            Listener.Start();
            Listener.BeginGetContext(ProcessRequest, Listener);
            Console.WriteLine("Connection Started");
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            Listener.Stop();
        }

        private void ProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            HttpListener listener = (HttpListener)result.AsyncState;
            HttpListenerContext context = listener.EndGetContext(result);

            string responseString = "<html>Hello World</html>";
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseString);

            context.Response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
            System.IO.Stream output = context.Response.OutputStream;
            output.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            output.Close();

            Listener.BeginGetContext(ProcessRequest, Listener);
        }
    }
```

Comment: IIS7 Is Much Faster, Multi-threaded Goodness

Comment: On the basic level, I suspect that `HttpListener` calls `http.sys`, thus the Http kernel queue should be the same

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The HttpListener class encapsulates the native API, [HttpSendHttpResponse Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364499(VS.85).aspx), which as stated in the link will always append the preposterous text to the server header information.

There's no way how to fix that, unless you want to code your HttpListener from scratch.

Answer (score 11):

I know I'm a little late but I was just recently trying to do the same thing and I accidentally came across a solution that works but I'm unsure if it has any repercussions.

```
Response.Headers.Add("Server", "\r\n\r\n");
```

Comment: Yeah, this line by itself removes the Server header in response. But when after that I add another Server Header I get this: **,My Server! Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0**

Comment: TY! totally fixed it! I mean it would be cool to add my own, but /meh.

Comment: `Response.Headers.Add("Server", "");` Should also work fine.

Comment: this weird hack pollutes the payload

Comment: This doesn't work anymore. It just throws an expection. Or somethimes, if it doesn't, it will remove other headers, because they will happen to be after two \r\n's.

Answer (score 1):

I did try, but it comes back with
My Personal Server Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0

I have also used with no success, set, remove, add, addheader

```
private void ProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            HttpListener listener = (HttpListener)result.AsyncState;
            HttpListenerContext context = listener.EndGetContext(result);

            string responseString = "<html>Hello World</html>";
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseString);
            context.Response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;

            //One
            context.Response.AddHeader("Server", "My Personal Server");

            //Two
            context.Response.Headers.Remove(HttpResponseHeader.Server);
            context.Response.Headers.Add(HttpResponseHeader.Server, "My Personal Server");

            //Three
            context.Response.Headers.Set(HttpResponseHeader.Server, "My Personal Server");

            System.IO.Stream output = context.Response.OutputStream;
            output.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            output.Close();

            Listener.BeginGetContext(ProcessRequest, Listener);
        }
```

Thanks
Elijah

Answer (score -2):

Arul's answer is correct, however, as Iain Ballard already noted, setting the Server header to an empty string will work, meaning the Server header will not be sent at all.
Then, if you have to let the client know what your awesome app's name is, you can take the liberty of adding a "Via" header. Its specifications are rather loose and it probably gets ignored by the majority of browsers.