# C# HttpListener. Sending EMPTY response (without any artefacts)

Tags: c#

I am using C# HttpListener class to realize some server. And here is the problem. I just want to send to client an empty response to the request like

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

or

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
```

without any additional text. So I set status code and status description and don't write any bytes to response OutputStream - I just don't need them. Then close the response to initiate sending bytes to the client with response.Close() method. And what I get on the client side shown by Fiddler is

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Transfer-Encoding: chunked

Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0

Date: Sun, 25 Oct 2015 10:42:12 GMT


0
```

There is a workaround for Server and Date fields -
[HttpListener Server Header c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427326/httplistener-server-header-c-sharp).

But how to remove these "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" artefact and "0" body from this response?!

Thanks to all in advance!

The code:

```
private void ProcessContext(HttpListenerContext aContext)
    {
        HttpListenerResponse response = aContext.Response;

        response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
        response.StatusDescription = "OK";
        response.Close();

}
```

Answer (score 17):

This will get rid of everything but the status and the `Content-Length` header:

```
HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
listener.Prefixes.Add("http://*:5555/");
listener.Start();
listener.BeginGetContext(ar =>
{
    HttpListener l = (HttpListener)ar.AsyncState;
    HttpListenerContext context = l.EndGetContext(ar);

    context.Response.Headers.Clear();
    context.Response.SendChunked = false;
    context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
    context.Response.Headers.Add("Server", String.Empty);
    context.Response.Headers.Add("Date", String.Empty);
    context.Response.Close();
}, listener);
```

and in fiddler you'll see this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Nasreddine! And is it possible to omit and "Content-Length" line. Our client waits form us just the bare "HTTP/1.1 200 OK". Don't ask why..

Comment: *And remove body zero length line too which is separated from the header with empty line.

Comment: @Pavel AFAIK it's not possible to modify the response of the HttpListener down to that level of detail. You can't even inherit them to override the behavior since they're sealed

Answer (score 4):

Just set `ContentLength64` to zero before closing response stream in order to transmit data the regular way:

```
response.ContentLength64 = 0;
response.OutputStream.Close();
```

If you flush or close response stream without setting content length to any value, data will be transmitted in chunks. And `0/r/n` in your response body is actually a closing chunk.